# Find the range of the function $f(x) = 4x + 8$ for the given domain $D = \{-5, -1, 0, 6, 10\}$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

The question is to find the range of each function for the given domain  $f(x)=4x+8$, $D=\{-5, -1, 0,6, 10\}$. Is the range just $R= \{-12,4,8,32,48\}$ or am I mistaken? Could you elaborate why my answers are correct?

Comment: $4\cdot(-5)+8=12$??? $4\cdot(-1)+8=-4$??? Yes, you are definitely mistaken in those two.

Comment: oops my bad. but otherwise is it correct?

Comment: Thanks! I had my doubts at my answers at first. But could you elaborate why my answers are correct?

Comment: Oh and is writing R= {-12,4,8,32,48} the correct way of writing the range by listing method?

Comment: Can you elaborate why (you think) your answer is correct? If so, then please do it **within** the question itself (i.e., not in a comment).

Comment: One comment: I would avoid using the word "range" and instead, depending on the context, use the less ambiguous words "image" or "codomain"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. The range (or image) of a function is just the set of all possible values of the function that you can get by plugging in values in the domain. If the domain is a finite list of numbers, you can find the range just by plugging in every number in the list, and removing duplicates.